# Laravel belongsTo coalesce?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, coalesce

I'm trying to add a relation to my `Booking` model. I already have a relation that looks like this:

```
public function vehicle() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
}
```

Which works on the column `bookings.vehicle_id`. However, now I'm adding another column called `bookings.billed_vehicle_id` which will "override" the `vehicle_id` if it's not null. So I want to do something like this:

```
public function billedVehicle() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class,DB::raw('coalesce(billed_vehicle_id,vehicle_id)'));
}
```

Is this possible?

And if not possible with `belongsTo` can I somehow create a custom relation that'll support this?

Answer (score 2):

`belongsTo()` returns a query builder so you can go ahead and just chain `->whereRaw()` on the end of it:

```
public function billedVehicle() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class)
        ->whereRaw(DB::raw('coalesce(billed_vehicle_id,vehicle_id)'));
}
```

Comment: Won't that add the extra condition *ontop* of the automatic condition? And how will this deal with aliases and joins and such? `billed_vehicle_id` and `vehicle_id` are not fully-qualified column names, but I don't know what alias Laravel will use for my `bookings` table, otherwise I'd add it in myself.

Comment: @mpen Those are great questions. Yes, that will add an extra condition on top of the automatic condition. Where are those aliases defined, curiously?

Comment: If you ever write a query that uses the same table twice, you'd need to give it an alias. I know you can do it with `->join('bookings as whatever', ...)`. Not sure if there's another way.

Comment: @mpen You shouldn't need to, Laravel should derive that automagically

Comment: If we use `DB::raw` Laravel won't patch the SQL to use the alias, and we'll end up with an SQL error because `billed_vehicle_id` and/or `vehicle_id` will be used twice.

Comment: This conversation is purely theoretical. This answer is not a solution to the question posed.